# the_content filter doesn't return html code, any substitute?

Tags: php, wordpress

I was working on a WordPress plugin, and I found that when the_content filter hook is used, it gives content of the post to the function as a parameter, but in plain-text format. I want to get the HTML content of the post, any way to achieve this?

Thanks
- Kapeel

Comment: I'm not sure if this is programming-related, and thus for *Stackoverflow*, or if it belongs on *webapps* now...

Comment: @ricebowl I dunno about anyone else but that seems a bit premature when there's just a warning message saying it's in private beta when you try to login.

Comment: @Ah, a valid point. I wasn't aware of the 'private' beta status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after searching a lot, I had solved it.

As said by TheDeadMedic - "Are you sure that the post content does actually contain HTML? Don't forget WordPress will add paragraphs on-the-fly, and won't necessarily store them in the DB."

WordPress does by using a function called `wpautop();`

I just used this with `get_the_content();` , and I got it working.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this -

```
function myPluginReplaceContent() {
    $content    =   wpautop(get_the_content());
    $content    .=  myPluginGetData(); // do whatever you want to - here
    return $content;
}
```

EDIT :

I found that this function won't apply filters by other plugins. The following function won't cause any issues.

```
function myPluginReplaceContent($thecontent) {      
    $thecontent .=  myPluginGetData(); // do whatever you want to - here
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any plugins installed, or are you filtering `the_content` elsewhere?

By default, the content passed through the filter `the_content` is pretty much what's in the database, minus a bit of parsing (handling <`!-- more -->` teasers etc.).

Are you sure that the post content does actually contain HTML? Don't forget WordPress will add paragraphs on-the-fly, and won't necessarily store them in the DB.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of your DB - is WordPress definitely stripping HTML, or is real the problem that there isn't any HTML stored?