# why is my content breaking out of div structure?

Tags: css, wordpress, text

I have a wordpress page and when I put my text in the html/css structure hardcode stye, it fits in properly but when I try to do it via wordpress `<?php echo the_content();?>` it breaks out of the structure.

Here is the hardcoded version versus the wordpress php generated version

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="about-text">
     hardcoded text stays in fine
  </p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="about-text">
        <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php echo the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: There must be something wrong in your content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172481/the-content-filter-doesnt-return-html-code-any-substitute

Comment: Please remove all these 3 tags, this question should go in css tag. One more thing, remove this php code and add the generated content here, or better is to create fiddle for it.. here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please provide the code generated by the_content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<p class="about-text"></p>` with `<div class="about-text"><div>`

`<? the_content; ?>` will generate paragraphs for you, so what you will end up with is invalid HTML as you will have `<p>` tags nested within another `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The_content generates paragraphs so, you have to handle the paragraphs in your CSS.
Like if you have content ABC then the_content will render it as

ABC

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress contents always wrapped in paragraph TAG, you need to adjust your css accordingly for paragraph tag,
by default paragraph tag has margins, so thats the reason your content breaks.